# Google Datastudio: Parameters from a datasource

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have a report in DataStudio and I can't solve the following problem:

I have a datasource (1), an SQL query, like the following:

```
SELECT
     user_id,
     user_name
FROM
     users;
```

I have another datasource (2), with a query similar to this one:

```
SELECT result
FROM (
   SELECT func1 (@user_id, @DS_START_DATE, @DS_END_DATE) as result
   UNION ALL
   SELECT func2 (@user_id, @DS_START_DATE, @DS_END_DATE) as result
   UNION ALL
   SELECT func3 (@user_id, @DS_START_DATE, @DS_END_DATE) as result
   UNION ALL
   ...
   UNION ALL
   SELECT func27 (@user_id, @DS_START_DATE, @DS_END_DATE) as result
)
```

func1, func2, etc. are all stored-functions within BigQuery. Each of them performs a different and complex calculation, which returns a number. Altogether there are 27 functions

I would like to be able to select the user in the datasource (1) and at this moment execute the datasource (2) passing the "user_id" as a parameter for each of the functions.

How can I do something like that?

I tried to use custom parameters, but it forces me to manually inform each of the "users_ids" and I would like this to come automatically from a database table (datasource[1]).

Some help?
Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart.